# How to partition correctly with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue job that does the ETL of a sales file and at the end partitions my file by date of sale, each partition receives the name of the column + the date of sale but within the file itself the content of the column that has the date of sale is empty, I don't know how to solve it

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

## Particionar o DataFrame por data (data_venda)

partitionedDataFrame = coalescedDataFrame.repartition("dt_venda")

## Gerar um arquivo .csv para cada partição (data_venda)

partitionedDataFrame.write.partitionBy("dt_venda").option("sep", ";").option("header", "true").mode("append").csv("s3://s3-aws-araujo-sf-cx360-cdp-dev/03-cleansed/venda/")

job.commit()

the idea is that the output file is named with the date referring to the sale and the file has all columns and records unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use Athena to query the data in S3 produced by Glue jobs. Athena creates columns for the partitions, so the final tables still have those columns just as it were in the original data.

In your case (without knowing what your use for the final data is) I would suggest duplicating columns under the different column names and based on what fits your requirements the best use either original or duplicate columns for partitioning.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

partitionedDataFrame = partitionedDataFrame.withColumn('dt_dup', col('dt_venda'))
# This will use new 'dt_dup' column for partitioning keeping the original column 'dt_venda' in the output files
partitionedDataFrame.write.partitionBy("dt_dup").option("sep", ";").option("header", "true").mode("append").csv("s3://s3-aws-araujo-sf-cx360-cdp-dev/03-cleansed/venda/")
```